# TPageControl/TTabSheet Position Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have some TTabSheet on TPageControl like these.

Tab1 Tab2 Tab3 Tab4

But I want my first tab start a specific position and so on;

```
      Tab1 Tab2 Tab3 Tab4
```

How can I set start position within Delphi XE? and mouse click will be work correctly.

Comment: do you want to make fixed padding before tabs?

Comment: Yes, I want to make fixed padding. First tab is start 50 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution is to add spaces in front of the caption of the first tab (see second sample in the image below).

But I would choose for inserting a dummy tab which cannot set active (see first sample) by implementing the `PageControl.OnChanging` event, as such:

```
procedure TForm1.PageControl1Changing(Sender: TObject;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  AllowChange := not PtInRect(PageControl1.TabRect(0),
    PageControl1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos));
end;
```

[image: Padding on tab caption]

Comment: These truly the easiest ways of doing this, however there are of course other more complex ways of doing so too, a subject probably worth investigating.

Comment: Looks like this way is very easy. But as you know you can not set the position and width of first tab also feeling is you have a empty tab in there.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the Raize controls. Their tabsheet control has a lot of flexibility, but I don't know if they do what you want. They have a nice downloadable demo program that you could play with to see if they do what you want. If you don't find what you want, you could also email them asking if it's possible.

This is not a free library, but, IMO, well worth the money. We use the Raize controls often and are very happy with them.