# TPageControl and Startmargin

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need a property for `TPageControl` like `StartMargin` in `TTabSet`. Does anyone have any idea, how can I create `StartMargin` property in `TPageControl`?

For anyone unfamiliar with [StartMargin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Tabs.TTabSet.StartMargin), here is the relevant text from its documentation:

> Determines how far, in pixels, the first tab appears from the left edge of the tab set control.

Comment: @David, I was unfamiliar with it but as far as I can see TPageControl does not actually contain a TTabset. So what the OP is asking for is tricky at least. So using an actual TTabSet looks the best way to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TPageControl/TTabSheet Position Delphi XE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817698/tpagecontrol-ttabsheet-position-delphi-xe)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, then you can do this with the standard controls.

In the object inspector Set TPageControl --> Margins --> Left to say 50. Then set AlignWithmargins to True.

Same applies to TTabSheet

Or do you need something different?

Edit ref your comment:
The same also applies to TTabSet: set the left margin, AlignWithMargins and align top on a panel. 
This gives you your effect.  But now you have to manage your own page visibility and page switching :(

Comment: TTabSheet's Left is 50 if I can do this. I do not want TTabSheet position is change or move. You know tab button on top or bottom (if TabPosition is tpTop or tpBottom) (TabSheet1, TabSheet2, etc) just these button start position (or Left position) change from different position. 
          ----------|----------|
          |TS1      |TS2       |
----------|---------|----------|
          |         |          |

Answer (score 0):

Or, for a multi-version solution:

```
uses 
  ..., 
  CommCtrl; 

type 
  TPageControl = class(ComCtrls.TPageControl) 
  private 
    procedure TCMAdjustRect(var Msg: TMessage); message TCM_ADJUSTRECT; 
  end; 

  TForm1 = class(TForm) 
    ... 
  end; 

... 

procedure TPageControl.TCMAdjustRect(var Msg: TMessage); 
begin 
  inherited; 
  if Msg.WParam = 0 then
    Inc(PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Left, 50)
  else
    Dec(PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Left, 50);
end;
```

Comment: This is moving TTabSheet. It is not affected to TPageControl button (Tabsheet1, TabSheet2), buttons are still in same position. I need TTabSheets are in same position only buttons are move to different position.

Comment: Then this question IS a duplicate... from yourself actually.